# Visual Studio Ionic App Packaging for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic2, provisioning-profile

I have an Ionic app I've developed using Visual Studio on a Windows machine.  I now want to package the app for iOS deployment and I can't get the remote build on the Mac to work to save my life.  I've wasted 3 days on this problem.

My build.json in my app is:

```
  "ios": {
    "release": {
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXXXXXXX",
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
      "packageType": "app-store",
      "provisioningProfile": "XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "buildFlag": [
        "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
        "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
        "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
      ]
    }
  }
```

I created an iOS distribution certificate using the latest XCODE on my MacInCloud:
[image]
Here is the certificate in the developer portal:
[image]
And then in the developer portal, I created Provisioning Profile, then downloaded it to my PC, opened it, extracted the Provisioning Profile UUID and put it into my build.json:
[image]
So then I do a remote build using my Mac in Cloud and I can watch the build take place but then by the end of the long build process, I eventually get this error:

> Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""Cincy Christmas.app"
>   requires a provisioning profile."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription="Cincy Christmas.app" requires a
>   provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to
>   the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property
>   list.}

I tried many different codeSignIdentity (iOS Distribution, iPhone Developer, etc...) and gotten multiple different errors (conflicting provisions, change to iPhone Developer, etc...)  I've also updated Cordova (7.0) and Cordova-ios (4.5.3) to see if that would fix it.  No dice.

What am I doing wrong?  Any ideas?  I'm at my wit's end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the provisioning profile isn't installed on the Mac you're using to build the app with. There are two ways to install profiles:

1. Launch Xcode and navigate to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts, then click on "Download Manual Profiles" or "Download All Profiles" (depending on whether you're using Xcode 9 or an older version).
2. You can download the profile from the Apple Developer portal to that Mac, then double-click the profile. This will launch Xcode and, unfortunately, you don't get any further UI feedback.

Next, open your project in Xcode and inspect the the "Signing" group under "General" and verify that the correct profile is selected.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to lengthen my already long explanation but I did try both suggestion 1 and 2 but got the same error.  Just to be thorough, I tried that again and still came up with the same error.  As for opening the project, do you mean open it in XCode?  Or in Visual Studio? I swear, I feel like an infant developer again whenever dealing with Apple stuff...lol

Comment: Open the project in Xcode to verify the signing properties are correct. I don't believe the issue is with Visual Studio.

Comment: So I can't figure out what the problem is with the Visual Studio remote cordova build, but once sherb told me to open it up in Xcode, I just found the xcodeproj generated from the remote cordova build, and built from there.  The signing on the general tab was correct, so I'm not really sure what the problem was.  I also don't care; I'll just manually build from Xcode after the cordova build for now.  Thanks SHERB!!!  One step closer!

Comment: Just to follow up (in case anyone stumbles upon this problem and needs more explanation), what I think happened is the changes Apple made to XCode no longer allows for the full build to happen through remotebuild.  So I opened the project on the Mac in Cloud and finished off the packaging and deployment from there.  Once I finished, it showed up automagically as a usable build and I was able to submit the app for review.